# Git - two different statuses on master

Tags: git

I wasn't very smart when I did this:
I worked on my computer on a project - always on master branch with a last commit that I forgot to push to the remote (GitHub).

My computer needed to be repaired and so I cloned the project on another computer (without the last commit) and started working on this one, again working on master only. I pushed the changes to the remote.

But know I can't push from computer 1 because obviously "the remote contains work that you do not have locally".

What is the best way now not to lose any changes? A soft reset and then pushing the changes to a new branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull first on computer 1. It should start a merge.

- If it merged cleanly, confirm that your code looks the way you want it to.
- If it didn’t merge cleanly, resolve conflicts so your code looks the way you want it to, then commit the merge.

Then push.

Comment: Ah perfect, I didn't think of that! Or rather I wasn't sure if it would not overwrite the changes. Thank you!